# Error in callback rate with CountDownTimer?

Tags: java, android

I have been building a small darkroom timer application, as I learn Android and java.
Ended up using CountDownTimer, as it does most of the work for me. :{)
However, I ran into what looks like an error in the class.

My initial structure used the onTick() callback to decrement my time counter, and update the time-remaining display. If I set it up for example:

```
            new CountDownTimer(60000, 100) {

                 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                     mDisplayTime.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished)/1000);
                     timeTenths -= 1;
                     updateDisplay();
                 }

                 public void onFinish() {
//                   mDisplayTime.setText("Done!");
                 }
              }.start();
```

The total timeout (60 seconds) is spot on, within half a second by my stopwatch.
However, the displayed count stops with 3.0 seconds on the clock.
Experimenting with it, I found a consistent 5% "shortage" in onTick() events.
I could change the second parameter to 950 milliseconds, but that's an ugly kludge...

In the end, I changed the onTick() to display actual millisUntilFinished, which is fine, and eliminates my counter as well.

Is this a known problem with CountDownTimer()?

Dave

Answer (score 0):

Before calling Google, have you done checking using LogCat? Namely in your `onTick` method you might want to debug what `millisUntilFinish` brings you and not only rely on TextView. Also, unless I understood something incorrectly, you might have to consider `onFinish()` your final 'tick'.

Comment: Showing my noob ignorance, what's LogCat?   Good thought on the final tick being onFinish(), but in my example it should tick 600 times (I mis-copied it as 60000/1000), and regularly comes up 30 short.

Comment: I really wouldn't rely `onTick` to be called exactly 600 times in that case case. What you ought to do is check how accurate its interval is. Once you receive `onTick`, store `millisUntilFinished`, and on next call subtract new millisUntilFinished from previous one to see how 'close' it is to 100ms. And [LogCat](http://www.droidnova.com/debugging-in-android-using-eclipse,541.html) makes it much easier to do this kind of a verification.